# String from SQL server to bitmap android

Tags: php, android, sql, web-services, bitmap

I am working on a project in android where I want to upload and download pictures to/from a SQL database.

I can perfect upload my pictures to it. I take a photo, convert this to a bitmap. This bitmap I can convert to a String. This string I send to a webserice to place it in a SQL database(this commum is of the type BLOB).
I see in my SQL things like 'BLOB-36.7KiB'. So I think the upload went succesfull.

But when I want to download the picture it goes wrong. 
Because I sended it like a string, I can receive it like a string as well. 
The string, that i receive is like (Log.d used) : `/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB`

When I convert this with next code to a bitmap it goes wrong.

```
  public Bitmap StringToBitMap(String encodedString){
        try{
            byte [] encodeByte= Base64.decode(encodedString, Base64.DEFAULT);
            Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0, encodeByte.length);
            return bitmap;
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.getMessage();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I get next error:

```
D/skia: --- decoder->decode returned false
```

So I think there goes something wrong with converting.
I don't know what, because the string that i receive is so short, I think I can't receive the whole string?
I have no idea how to fix this.
This is the code of my web-service.

```
 $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('Unable to Connect');
$number = $_POST['data'];


 $sql ="SELECT Image FROM images WHERE Number=".$number;
    $result= mysqli_query($con, $sql);

   if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        $image = $row["Image"];
    }
   }

 print($image); 
}
```

This is the code for my app, to receive the image.

```
 private void getImage() {

        class GetImage extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{
            ProgressDialog loading;
            RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                loading = ProgressDialog.show(PhotoViewer.this, "Uploading...", null,true,true);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                loading.dismiss();
                Bitmap bitmap = StringToBitMap(s);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                String param = params[0];
                Log.d(TAG,param);


                HashMap<String,String> data = new HashMap<>();
                data.put("data", param);
                String result = rh.sendPostRequest(DOWNLOAD_URL,data);
                Log.d(TAG,result);
                return result;
            }
        }

        GetImage gi = new GetImage();
        gi.execute(place.getFotoNumber());
    }
public class RequestHandler{
    public String sendPostRequest(String requestURL,HashMap<String, String> postDataParams) {

        URL url;
        String response = "";
        try {
            url = new URL(requestURL);

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);


            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));

            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();
            int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

            if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                response = br.readLine();
            } else {
                response = "Error Registering";
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return response;
    }

}
```

I hope you guys can help me.

Thanks,
StijnB